# Isblank in visualflow always returning the same value

Tags: formula, visual-workflow, isblank

My flow starts with a screen element that has two fields. Then it proceeds to a screen element that outputs both fields and two formulas. The formulas follow the format of `ISBLANK(Field1)` and again for field 2.

When I run the flow I put in a value for field 1 and leave field 2 blank. Here I expect `ISBLANK(Field1)` to return false, but why isn't `ISBLANK(Field2)` returning true?

[image]

Comment: A good workaround is to use LEN(field1)<1. But that doesn't really answer my question about why it doesn't work as expected.